# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Ранения как у солдат". Нужна ли в этом случае запятая? Какое здесь действует правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какое здесь действует правило?

Это -- http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125 :

> **§ 90.** Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно,
> будто, точно, как будто, что **не
> выделяются запятыми** в следующих
> случаях:
>
> <...>
>
> в) **если оборот является сказуемым:**
> ***Снег** у крыльца **как песок** зыбучий*